# Single word for something which receives a request to do something then does it

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for something or someone which receives requests to perform different tasks at a specified time, then according to the specified time (given with the task) either immediately or at a specific later date performs that task?

Comment: You mean like a scheduler or were you thinking of something more along the lines of a minion, robot, or servo?

Comment: In specific cases, the scheduler may be a "sequencer", i.e.  *a device for the automatic determination or regulation of a sequence* ?

Comment: That would be a *server*, or the scheduler component thereof.

Answer (score 2):

**Executor.**

From [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) software definition:

> ... executes submitted [...] tasks. [...] provides a way of decoupling task submission from the mechanics of how each task will be run, including details of thread use, scheduling, etc

**EDIT**:
Or more specifically you could say a [scheduled executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: Scheduler is more appropriate. The executor does not do the time or delay scheduling.

Comment: Agree Scheduler may be fine; Edited to